Are there any items that appear in Skyrim as a stack that is not found in a chest?
In Skyrim, a lone cabbage is a single cabbage, as is a piece of gold. A pile of gold is represented by a bag (a single item) and not a gold piece, as are arrows. Stacked items only seem to appear in chests, despite it being possible for the player to drop stacked items, which may be "immersion breaking", but is a common game mechanic.
Are there any world items (not contained in a chest) to be found in Skyrim which break this theme and are themselves stacks of items with only a single item visible in the world?

I think, but I'm not sure, that I've encountered stacks of ores or ingots that were actually piles. On the other hand, I can imagine that the artists who put together the game world exclusively used single items as set dressing. We also often come across piles of gold (often literal piles) that are in fact stacks of single coins. As you point out, this might have been done for internal consistency.

The way to check this would be to run through all of the Reference records in Skyrim.esm (and the other ESM files) and look for any with a count other than 1. I know that xEdit has a scripting interface that is probably capable of doing that, but frankly I don't speak Delphi and don't really feel like learning it. Based on what the CK wiki says, you would also need to exclude arrows, and maybe gold, because those really are just stacks internally even though they look like separate objects.

Dropping 30-odd soul husks on a table in Valerica's study results in what looks like one soul husk on the table.
